# Deleting a node in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to delete a node in a linked list. I am first experimenting on how to delete the head and the tail nodes. The head deletion seems to work, however the tail the deletion does not. When I run the code, the place where the tail used to be is replaced with garbage values. Can anyone figure out why? Many thanks!

```
void CList :: Remove() {

    int data = NULL;

    std::cout<<"Enter value you wish to remove ";
    std:: cin>> data;

    cNode *pMyPointer = m_pHead;

    while (pMyPointer != NULL)
    {
        if (pMyPointer->m_nValue == data) {
            std::cout << "Element found";
            goto del;
        }

        else {
            pMyPointer = pMyPointer->m_pNext;
        }   
    }

    del:

    //removing the head
    if (pMyPointer == m_pHead)
        m_pHead= m_pHead->m_pNext;
    //removing the tail
    else if (pMyPointer == m_pTail)
        m_pTail = m_pTail->m_pPrev;

    delete pMyPointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider node_1 points to node_2 (just a 2 node case) 
Just look at this code

```
else if (pMyPointer == m_pTail)
        m_pTail = m_pTail->m_pPrev;
```

node_1 points to node_2 . It still points there . once you deleted node_2 , node_1 will still point to node_2 (or garbage once node_2 is deleted) & so you must make sure node_1 points to NULL . ie last but one should point to null .

something like

```
else if (pMyPointer == m_pTail)
    m_pTail->m_pPrev->next=NULL;
    m_pTail = m_pTail->m_pPrev;
```

Answer (score 1):

With this statement

```
 while (pMyPointer != NULL)
```

Your pointer may be pointing to NULL when it exits the loop and hence it will skip the tail pointer.

Instead try

```
while (pMyPointer->m_pNext != NULL)
```

You also need to make the second last node point to NULL.

```
else if (pMyPointer == m_pTail) {
  m_pTail = m_pTail->m_pPrev;
  m_pTail->m_pNext = NULL;
}
delete pMyPointer;
```

Also, instead of `goto del`, just use `break;`

Comment: the new condition does not work, the program still crashes and prints garbage values where the tail used to be. i have arranged the goto del, thanks for the tip!

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but I saw MAG user's answer before yours. I would answer both correct answers if i could!

Answer (score 0):

Stay one node ahead of the node you want to delete

Comment: could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: He means if you want to delete node 3, you have to traverse the linked list to node 2 then go to node 3, delete him and go ahead to node 4. Now you have to save the address of node 2 to the previous address of node 4 (if the list is double linked) and node 4 to the next address of node 2.

Answer (score 0):

And what if your tail and head pointer are the same? You don't check for it. Therefore you might be deleting the pointer which you assume to be the Head, which is also a Tail. Plus what if it's Next for a Head or Prev for a Tail?

```
void CList :: Remove() {

    int data = NULL;

    std::cout<<"Enter value you wish to remove ";
    std:: cin>> data;

    cNode *pMyPointer = m_pHead;

    while (pMyPointer != NULL)
    {
        if (pMyPointer->m_nValue == data) {
            std::cout << "Element found";
            goto del;
        }

        else {
            pMyPointer = pMyPointer->m_pNext;
        }   
    }

    del:

     //taking care of the neighbors
    if (pMyPointer->m_pPrev)
        pMyPointer->m_pPrev->m_pNext = pMyPointer->m_pNext;
    if (pMyPointer->m_pNext)
        pMyPointer->m_pNext->m_pPrev = pMyPointer->m_pPrev;
    // removing the head
    if (pMyPointer == m_pHead)
        m_pHead= m_pHead->m_pNext;
    //removing the tail
    if (pMyPointer == m_pTail)
        m_pTail = m_pTail->m_pPrev;

    delete pMyPointer;
}
```